# How many claymores can I have out at a time?

Tags: battlefield-3

So in BF3, the support class can lay antipersonnel mines (claymores).  He can also reload himself with ammunition, providing him with a never-ending stream of claymores, if he desires.  How many of them actually persist on the map?  If I run around the map and lay down 20 claymores, how many of them are actually there?  All 20?  The last X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a maximum of 2 claymores deployed at one time.

<s>Additionally, claymores (unlike mines) do not survive your death, so plan accordingly.</s>

As of the December 6th patch, claymores now survive your death.

Comment: Really? I'm fairly sure I've more than two out at a time....

Comment: @Albort You can place more than two, but when your third hits the ground, your oldest one disappears.